# Using OO concept in jQuery, using function() and creating array of structure

Tags: jquery, oop, object, multidimensional-array, structure

This is regarding using OO concepts in jQuery.

I want to create an array of structures in jQuery so that I can save a char and an  integer in same the element of an array.

I want to store 'Y' and 2 in each element of array, so that I can change the value of the integer based on whether the value of the char is 'Y'.

I have the following code

```
        var arrOfArr = new Array(3);
        for (var x = 0; x < arrOfArr.length; x++) {
            arrOfArr[x] = [new struct('Y', 0),new struct('Y', 0),new struct('Y', 0)];
        }

        function struct($user, $turnCount) {
            var user = $user;
            var turnCount = $turnCount;
        }
```

Now when I call `alert(arrOfArr[0][0].turnCount)`, it is giving `undefined`. But if I define `arrOfArr[0][0].turnCount = 0` and again call the same alert it gives me 0.

Can you please help me understand how can I initialize an array of structures at the time of initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var user
```

and

```
var turnCount
```

are private variables to structs scope

try using

```
this.user = $user;
this.turnCount = $turncount;
```

Comment: This worked for me. Can you please tell that we used user and turnCount without defining them in function. Can we do that in jquery and it understand that user and turnCount belongs to this? In C++ and java, we first define variable like int i and then use it like this.i.

Comment: `this.turnCount` for example is really applying the property turnCount to `this` that is the object representing the class `struct`. In JS, declaring a variable with `var` maintains the scope it is declared in whereas using `this` places the value within the classes object when constructed with `new struct(x, y)`. This is similar to the private and public variables in other OO languages.

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning to local variables instead of instance properties in your constructor.

Try writing:

```
function struct($user, $turnCount) {
    this.user = $user;
    this.turnCount = $turnCount;
}
```